# C# Form Application: How to avoid deleting the unwanted events "manually" from InitializeComponent()?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a simple scenario:

I add an event to a control on the form by double clicking on its field (in Events part). But, then I decide that it was unnecessary and delete the automatically generated method. I'll run the program and it gives an error telling me that the event still exists in the `InitializeComponent()` and I must delete it from there.

So, is there anyway to avoid deleting the event "manually"? Is there anyway to fully delete it without leaving any trace (specially in `InitializeComponent()`)?

**Update:** Also, another question arose:

When I delete the method from the code, the method name in the event field will disappear. So, if the `InitializeComponent()` is linked to these events, why isn't it updated with the empty event field?

Comment: You could simple edit the form's Designer.cs file and delete the single line that assigns the event.  Editing InitializeComponent is usually not recommended, but you can't mess this up.  Also, when you discover this immediately then simply type Ctrl+Z and click Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use again the events grid and right click on the event you have inserted.
Select the Reset Menu option. This will remove the event handler assigned in the InitializeComponent and the code of the **emtpy** event in the code designer.

Note, that if you add code at the event, Visual Studio doesn't remove the new code.

Comment: +1, that works. So, basically there is no way to deleting it from the code itself? (I was hoping some refactoring or something...)

Comment: @FlomEnol no, to my knowledge the only way to remove from code is the manual edit. The standard refactor tool doesn't provide any help. Also, I use CodeRush and there is no command for this. I don't know if it is possible in ReSharper or other tools.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is through the Properties grid in the Designer. You can click the Reset button or just delete the text and it will remove the event hook-up in the InitializeComponent() method. If your method is empty in your code behind, it will also delete it there:

[image]

It makes sense that you would have to manually delete the method body if it contains code in case it accidentally got Reset in the designer or if your method is referenced from some other part of your code. Visual Studio is gong to err on the side of caution.

If you delete the method body first, the reason it is not deleting the references to it probably in part has to do with cutting-and-pasting code. If you wanted to move the method to a different place in your code, the acting of cutting it would sever the references to it.  After you pasted it, then you would wonder why your event was no longer be called.  Again, error on the side of caution since it's not that difficult for the developer to track down extraneous code.

Comment: You're wrong about it deleting the empty method. I tested it (also see the Botz3000 answer below), the empty method was still in the code.

Comment: I can't explain why you two are not seeing the empty methods get deleted, @FlomEnol, but your question was about deleting it from the code and having it also be deleted from `InitializeComponent().` Regardless, even if it doesn't delete it on some occasions, it's an empty method body that won't harm anything and will stand out in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The question was more out of curiosity than anything else. I just wanted to know if there's something I'm missing here. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This pertains to C# 2017. So hopefully it would help others.

I'm new to C# (or at least back to code it) and ran with the same issue.

I commented out the event that I did by mistake. Then in the Error list, you will find an error there because that event is missing. Double click on it. It'll take you to the Designer code that "wires" the event. Once there, find the unwanted event and comment it out/delete it. Take care!

Answer (score 1):

In the designer you go to the events tab for the control in question, select the event that has the unwanted handler; and delete the name of the handler.  Then save the form again.

This doesn't delete the method itself I think, (possibly unless it's empty or just been added).

**Update**

I dare say the reason for why it nearly always *doesn't* delete the method is because it could be used as a handler on another control's event.  After all, in the UI you only asked to remove *one* event's handler; not every handler bound to that method.  Then there's the question of whether the back-end code is dirty (i.e. unsaved) - checking whether the method is empty or not isn't reliable in that case.  Yes, all of these could be worked around, but having to delete the method manually isn't *exactly* a hardship :) and at least this way VS doesn't end up deleting methods you actually want to keep.

Comment: As *Botz3000* also mentioned, it doesn't always delete the empty method.

Comment: @FlomEnol yeah see my updated answer.  I think, basically, whatever means it uses to track whether the method can be deleted is  by-design quite flaky to ensure it doesn't delete anything you actually want.

Comment: It "nearly" sounds reasonable to me. The problem here (as it seems) is the method-emptiness checking part. Also, I know deleting manually isn't a *hardship*, but the thing I hate the most is deleting every instance of it!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the properties window when you select the Control. Click on the little flash and you'll see the Events listed, along with your event (Click or whatever), and your event will have the name of the assigned method behind it. Just delete that method.

That deletes the method, only if it's empty and otherwise unused though, which is quite reasonable. After all you might have put a lot of work into that event handler. (note: Just tried it again and apparently it doesn't always delete empty methods even though it did a few minutes ago. weird.)

Comment: Correct. But, you agree, the behavior of this event handling and empty events are a little strange?

Comment: @FlomEnol - I think it's quite reasonable - as I've said in an update to my answer, the handler might be used on another event (even if it's empty you only asked it to remove it from one event)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the form and hit CTRL+Z.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. It seems pretty dangerous! I know I don't want a certain event but most of the times I'm not sure it was the last change I made in the form.

Comment: If you're making changes afterward, then, yeah, don't do this.

Comment: However, if it's the first thing you do (say, you created the event by accident, or you change your mind immediately), then this is a complete solution.